# How to bundle and access resources in Kotlin Multiplatform for native targets like linuxX64?

Tags: kotlin, resources, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I want to bundle a file along with my Kotlin Multiplatform library. The library supports both JVM and linuxX64 targets.

On the JVM, I am able to access a bundled file using `MyClass::class.java.getResourceAsStream()` and friends.

But on linuxX64, how can we do this? We just need to get a path to the bundled resource. After that, opening a file and reading it should be easy.

- Is bundling of resources supported at all?
- If it is supported, how do we get the path to a bundled resource file?

Compose Multiplatform seems to have some solutions for bundling resources, as described here:
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md

But

- this would work only for apps, not libraries
- it is for apps that use Compose

I am also aware of projects such as `moko-resource`, but it also doesn't have a solution for native libraries. It only supports apps on iOS, Android and Web.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately **KMM** doesn't provide solution for this right now (and probably won't provide in the nearest future), it requires to create some kind of Resource Manager for **Kotlin/Native**. It is big architecture decision and looks like it is not priority right now. You can track progress for this in [Kotlin's Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49981/Multiplatform-API-to-access-library-and-application-resources).

As workaround you can create task that adds resources to `.klib` in Gradle build of your library (`.klib` already has special `resources` folder that you could use for this, it is empty for non-JVM targets by default), but your library consumers should somehow pack those resources with the final executable ([see example](https://github.com/msink/kotlin-libui/blob/66bc56da509c18fc2322f3cd90b138b72ddc0070/samples/build.gradle#L8)).